# C++ Переделать функцию для STL list контейнера

Tags: c++, list, stl, linked-list

Написала функцию, которая ищет определенный элемент в одностороннем связанном списке и если его нет - добавляет его в начало списка. Было бы интересно узнать, как переделать данную функцию для STL list контейнера.

```
bool push_front(elem* &p, elem* &first) {
   elem *pointer = first;

   while (pointer) {
       if (pointer->val == p->val) {
           return false;
       } 
       pointer = pointer->next;
   }

   p->next = first;
   first = p;
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Что-то вроде

```
int value;
list<int> L;

if (find(L.begin(),L.end(),value) == L.end())
    L.push_front(value);
```

Но `list` - он двусвязный; если хотите односвязный - замените `list` на `forward_list`.

Comment: а можно искать не числовое значение, а элемент типа string?

Comment: Ну, заменяете `int` на `string`... Или на еще какой нужный тип.